# 4-regular planar graph is unique?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I'm working on a project for a class and as part of that project I (previously) decided to do the following problem from our textbook, *Combinatorics and Graph Theory* 2nd ed. by Harris, Hirst, & Mossinghoff.

> Find a 4-regular planar graph, and prove that it is unique.

(Now that I'm posting this I will be using a different problem for my project whether I get help on this or not.)  The issue I'm having is that I don't really buy this.  "4-regular" means all vertices have degree 4.  A "planar" representation of a graph is one where the edges don't intersect (except technically at vertices).  Below are two 4-regular planar graphs which do not appear to be the same or even isomorphic.  The first one [comes from this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/241162/307169) and the second one [comes from this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/242855/307169).

What's going on?  Am I just missing something trivial here?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, I agree.  We need something more than just $4$-regular and planar to make the graph unique.  You give examples with $8$ vertices and with $12$ vertices.  I can think of planar $4$-regular graphs with $10$ and with infinitely many vertices.

Comment: One thought would be to check the textbook's definition.  While you and I take $4$-regular to mean simply each vertex having degree $4$ (four edges at each vertex), it is possible the book defined it to mean something stronger.

Comment: @hardmath, thanks, that's all the confirmation I need.  Re: definition in the book, it just says "A graph $G$ is *regular* if every vertex has the same degree.  $G$ is said to be *regular of degree $r$* (or *$r$-regular*) if $\deg(v) = r$ for all vertices $v$ in $G$."  I wonder if there's some "we make such-and-such assumption only for this section" that I missed..

Comment: I added an image of the smallest such graph to [this recent Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020241/smallest-graph-that-cannot-be-represented-by-the-intersection-graph-of-axis-alig).

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is that once you fix the order (the number of vertices) of the 4-regular planar graph then it might be unique.

Comment: @LaarsHelenius I was also thinking that at one point.  I tried checking the author's website for errata to see if that condition was omitted from the problem but the errata link is broken.  Sigh.

Comment: @LaarsHelenius: For orders $n=6$ and $n=9$, the $4$-regular planar graph is unique.  The case $n=6$ is an octahedron (equiv. triangular antiprism), and the case $n=9$ is discussed at the end of my Answer.

Comment: Would you mind adding the title and author of your textbook to the Question?

Comment: @hardmath, added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if we fix the number of vertices, the (connected) $4$-regular planar graph of that order (number of vertices) may not be unique.  According to [work by Markus Meringer](http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/reggraphs.html#PLANAR), author of [GENREG](http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/manual/genreg.html), the only orders for which there is a unique such graph are likely to be $n=6,8,9$.

An [antiprism graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiprism_graph) with $2n$ vertices can be given as an example of a vertex-transitive (and therefore regular), polyhedral (and therefore planar) graph.

The pentagonal antiprism looks like this:

[image: pentagonal antiprism]

There is a different (non-isomorphic) $4$-regular planar graph with ten vertices, namely the [elongated square dipyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elongated_square_bipyramid):

[image: elongated square bipyramid]

Non-isomorphism of the graphs can be demonstrated by counting edges of [open neighborhoods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(graph_theory)) in the two graphs.  The open neighborhood of each vertex of the pentagonal antiprism has three edges forming a simple path.  In the elongated square dipyramid some open neighborhoods have two edges that form a path and some have four edges that form a cycle.

**Notes about the small odd vertex cases**

The only $4$-regular graph on *five* vertices is $K_5$, which of course is not planar.

Nonexistence of any $4$-regular planar graph on *seven* vertices was the topic of [this previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244099/a-4-regular-graph-with-7-vertices-is-non-planar).

**Uniqueness** of the $4$-regular planar graph on *nine* vertices was mentioned in [this previous Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/929212/3111).  The elegant illustration below, the dual of [the Herschel graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herschel_graph), is from [David Eppstein](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/613819/david-eppstein):

[image: dual Herschel graph]

Answer (score 1):

I know I asked this a while ago, but since this question seems to attract attention every now and then I figured I should post this.

I found a working errata link for this book [(I previously couldn't)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2041342/4-regular-planar-graph-is-unique/3723721#comment4191432_2041342) and it turns out the question was missing some information.  [http://www.appstate.edu/~hirstjl/bib/CGT_HHM_2ed_errata.html](http://www.appstate.edu/%7Ehirstjl/bib/CGT_HHM_2ed_errata.html)

Here's the relevant portion of the link, emphasis on missing parts mine:

> - p. 80, exercise 10 of section 1.5.2 should read: "Find a 4-regular planar graph **with triangular regions**, and prove that it is unique."

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge I guess the author just wanted us to prove that it is unique when the number of vertices is $6$. Like for a maximum planar graph we cant have two different graphs $G1$ and $G2$ satisfying $4$ regularity as well as planarity.