# Is there a four-regular plane graph with 25 vertices that meets corresponding conditions?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

The first thing I want to say is whether there is a **25th-order**  4-regular planar graph. I found some websites on the Internet, trying to find some clues. Indeed, I found some.

1. [4-regular planar graph is unique?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2041342/4-regular-planar-graph-is-unique)
2. http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/reggraphs.html#PLANAR

I think the second website is great！
In the second URL, surprisingly, there is no any relevant information about the  4-regular planar graph with 25 vertices.
[image]

I also try to solve it programmatically, but it seems relatively difficult, the number of vertices is a bit large. I tried to derive the contradiction through Euler’s formula, but failed.
[plantri](http://combos.org/plantri)

**If it does not exist, then the following question seems to become meaningless.**

---

Actually we want to find a simple  $4$-regular plane graph with $25$ vertices, which satisfies the following conditions:

(1) Each face is either a **3-degree face** or a **4-degree face**.

(2) There is exactly **one vertex** associated with **all 4-degree faces**, and all the other vertices are associated with ** one 3-degree face** and **three 4-degree face**.

Of course it may not exist.

PS: We can derive some information about the number of faces
Combine the following two formulas

$$3 f_3+4 f_4=2m=25\times 4$$

$$25- \frac{4\times 25}{2}+f_3+f_4=2$$

We get the number of three-degree face is $f_3=8$ and the number of three-degree face is $f_4=19$.

Comment: @ Morgan Rodgers  Thanks！Yes, just I’d like to find a 4 regular planar graph that meets the conditions I said. I doubt a little that it doesn't exist. First remove those conditions, that is, the 25-vertex 4-regular plane graph may not exist. The help of a computer is one of the ideas for finding the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Edit:] A previous version of this question asked about graphs where the 24 nonspecial vertices were each on 3 $3$-degree faces and a single $4$-degree face.**

This is impossible.

Let $\Gamma$ be such a graph, and let $u$ be the unique vertex that is on four $4$-degree faces. A simple counting argument shows that $\Gamma$ has 24 $3$-degree faces and $7$ $4$-degree faces. This means that there is at least one $4$-degree face $F$ that does not contain $u$. But the fact that each vertex on $F$ is only on other $3$-degree faces forces the structure of this graph, there will be only 8 vertices.

(I don't have the graph drawing ready, it will be a four-cycle with triangles on each edge, there will be one way to draw the remaining four edges.)

Comment: Thank you for your attention to my question. I added the information about the number of faces I got in the question, which seems to be different from what you got.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo before.

Comment: Hello! Before you reply to the answer, I have already revised it.But I still apologize for the trouble

Comment: Thanks again !I'm looking forward to your details  of proof.

Comment: I will try. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @  Morgan Rodgers I have proved through CaGe software that there is no such graph. Further, I am considering the combined proof.